# Understanding Error Propogation in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm using the Google Maps API with Node to get the formatted address of a particular location. The Maps API returns an empty array when no matching location can be found, so I'm trying to throw an error when the response array is empty using the following code:

```
function timeZoner(queryString) {
    const mapsApiKey = 'API_KEY';
    const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
        key: mapsApiKey
    });
    const VError = require('VError');

    googleMapsClient.geocode({
        address: queryString
    }, function(err, response) {

        if (!err) {

            returnedResults = response.json.results;
            if (returnedResults.length < 1) {
                console.log('no match found');
                var err1 = new Error;
            }

            var err2 = new VError(err1, 'no matched location');
            console.log(err2.message);

        } else {
            console.log('Maps API error');
        }
    });
};

timeZoner('this location name will not match');
```

Based on the example above, console will log 'no match found' as expected, but `err1` is never set, or at least isn't triggering `err2` and logging its message in the console as I think it should based on [the VError docs](https://github.com/joyent/node-verror). Can someone offer insight on why the error isn't getting triggered?

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around errors in Node as I'm relatively new to JS and I'm brand new to Node. I am aware of [error-first callbacks](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_first_callbacks) and see that the fact that `googleMapsClient.geocode` might be the reason the error isn't triggering, but I thought VError was supposed to assist with this. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean "triggering"?  `Error`/`VError` are just regular JavaScript objects...they can be instantiated (with `new`) or passed by reference, so I don't know what you mean by "triggering"....  Usually, `Error`/`VError` instances are designed to be thrown (through probably not in an async callback) or passed around...so just creating them and immediately logging them isn't going to do much....

Comment: Without using throw. You've made objects that do nothing.

Comment: adding `throw` to the error/verror objects doesn't seem to change anything. Maybe trying to rearrange the code in the error first callback format?